# Balls in a specific metric

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

could you help me with the following please:

Let $(\mathbb{R},d_{x}),(\mathbb{R},d_{y})$ metric spaces, prove that $d:\mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by:

$d(<x,y>,<x’,y’>)=d_{x}(x,x’)$

define a metric.  How is the unit ball displayed?
I already proved that it is metric, could you help me please see the unit balls with this metric, thank you very much.

Comment: Which are the points whose distance from $\langle 0,0\rangle$ is less than $1$?

Comment: It is no metric.

Comment: @Paul Frost Damn, I thought I had tried it right, why isn't it metric?

Comment: $d(<0,0>,<0,1>) = 0$.

Comment: But it is a pseudometric https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudometric_space and thus has unit balls in a generalized sense.